# What is the origin of 付いてる meaning "to be lucky"?

Tags: etymology, expressions

Where does that come from? Was "to be attached" the only original meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many people have wondered why, but I failed to find the authoritative explanation for this. At least デジタル大辞泉 says nothing more than that ツキ means luck. (By the way, this kind of 付き is usually written either in hiragana or katakana, perhaps because even native speakers don't know why the kanji 付 is associated with this word.)

Anyway, つく (憑く) sometimes means "(for a devil/ghost) to possess", "to haunt", etc. The most popular explanation seems to be that 付いている is from something like "Fortune is with me" or "God of fortune is being with me".

Actually, 何かが憑いている or 憑かれている is something you can say if you feel you're very unlucky.

- [付き、ツキとは何か](http://www.fleapedia.com/%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9/%E3%81%A4/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D-%E3%83%84%E3%82%AD%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B/)
- [運がいいときに「ツイてる」といいますけど、「ツイてる」の語源ってなんですか？](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1460140249)
- [「ツキを呼び込む」のツキを漢字にすると どう書きますか？ また 語源はなんでしょうか？](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1387642863)